# How to show SD in seaborn.tsplot() instead of SEM?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to show the standard deviation in a `tsplot()` instead of the standard error of the mean. Looks like the `'ci_band'` option shows the latter.

If this is possible, does anyone know of any example on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Not possible, sorry.

Comment: There is a workaround in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293687/standard-deviation-and-errors-bars-in-seaborn-tsplot-function-in-python?lq=1) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**2015-11-14**

Not possible.

I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/763).