# standard deviation and errors bars in seaborn tsplot function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

How does Seaborn compute its error bars? example:

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(22)
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(color_codes=True)
x = np.linspace(0, 15, 31)
data = np.sin(x) + np.random.rand(10, 31) + np.random.randn(10, 1)
ax = sns.tsplot(data=data, err_style="ci_bars")
plt.show()
```

how are the ci_bars (or ci_bands) calculated?

also, is it possible to make `tsplot` plot in ci_bars style where the error bars or bands correspond to **the standard deviation** of the values at each time point? (and not standard error of mean, or bootstraps)

Comment: @mwaskom: my additional question is how to plot bars or bands in ``tsplot`` that reflect standard deviation, not standard error of mean or a bootstrap estimate. is this possible? for my data bootstraps are too narrow and stdev is better representation

Answer (score 19):

In **Seaborn v0.8.0 (July 2017)** was added the ability to use error bars to show standard deviations rather than bootstrap confidence intervals in most statistical functions by putting ci="sd". So this now works

```
sns.tsplot(data=data, ci="sd")
```

**For previous Seaborn versions** a workaround for plotting standard deviation could be to use matplotlib errorbar on top of seaborn tsplot:

```
import numpy as np;
import seaborn as sns;
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a group of time series
num_samples = 90
group_size = 10
x = np.linspace(0, 10, num_samples)
group = np.sin(x) + np.linspace(0, 2, num_samples) + np.random.rand(group_size, num_samples) + np.random.randn(group_size, 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(group.T, index=range(0,num_samples))

# plot time series with seaborn
ax = sns.tsplot(data=df.T.values) #, err_style="unit_traces")

# Add std deviation bars to the previous plot
mean = df.mean(axis=1)
std  = df.std(axis=1)
ax.errorbar(df.index, mean, yerr=std, fmt='-o') #fmt=None to plot bars only

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Since the `tsplot` function does not provide a way to set the error bar values directly or to change the method used to calculate them, the only solution I found was to monkey patch the `timeseries` module:

```
import seaborn.timeseries

def _plot_std_bars(*args, central_data=None, ci=None, data=None, **kwargs):
    std = data.std(axis=0)
    ci = np.asarray((central_data - std, central_data + std))
    kwargs.update({"central_data": central_data, "ci": ci, "data": data})
    seaborn.timeseries._plot_ci_bars(*args, **kwargs)

def _plot_std_band(*args, central_data=None, ci=None, data=None, **kwargs):
    std = data.std(axis=0)
    ci = np.asarray((central_data - std, central_data + std))
    kwargs.update({"central_data": central_data, "ci": ci, "data": data})
    seaborn.timeseries._plot_ci_band(*args, **kwargs)

seaborn.timeseries._plot_std_bars = _plot_std_bars
seaborn.timeseries._plot_std_band = _plot_std_band
```

Then, to plot with the standard deviation error bars use

```
ax = sns.tsplot(data, err_style="std_bars", n_boot=0)
```

or

```
ax = sns.tsplot(data, err_style="std_band", n_boot=0)
```

to plot with a standard deviation band.

Edit: Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24890566/2997179) on SO, another (probably more sensible) approach would be to use the following instead of `tsplot`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "mean": data.mean(axis=0),
    "std": data.std(axis=0)
}).reset_index()

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, size=6)
ax = g.map(plt.errorbar, "index", "mean", "std")
ax.set(xlabel="", ylabel="")
```

Edit2: Since you asked about how `tsplot` calculates its confidence intervals: it uses [bootstrapping to estimate the distribution of the mean value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)#Estimating_the_distribution_of_sample_mean) at each time point and then finds the low and high percentile values (that correspond to the confidence interval being used) from these distributions. The default confidence interval is 68% – equivalent to ± one standard deviation of the mean, assuming normal distribution. The respective low and high percentiles are 16% and 84%. You can change the confidence interval via the `ci` keyword argument.

Comment: Thanks Martin, nice workaround. Unfortunately the python interpreter complains about the syntax just after  '*args' argument